# After querySelectorAll("input") do something with only a specfic type

Tags: javascript, queryselectall

I am making a validation function which displays an appropriate messagge for `patternMismatch`.

So far it displays the messagge, but it's the same for all input types.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(function(input){

  input.addEventListener("blur", function() {

    if (input.validity.patternMismatch) {
      if (e_space) {
        e_space.textContent = "This field can only contain letters from a-z.";
        input.classList.add("b-r");
      }
    }

})
```

Now I am trying to display different messagges for different `input type`s, but I can't seem to find a way to select a specific type.

I have tryed `if(input.type["text"])`, `if(input.type.text)` and `if(input["type=text"]` but no messagge gets displayed.

ie:

```
if(input.type["text"]){
  if(input.validity.patternMismatch){
     if(e_space){
        e_space.textContent = "This field can only contain letters from a-z.";
        input.classList.add("b-r");
     }
  input.classList.add("input-red");
  }
}
```

Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91vjt870/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.matches` to check if the input being iterated over matches a particular selector - such as, if it has an attribute:

```
if (input.matches('[type="text"]')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
if (input.type=="text") { 
          //Whatever
}
```